# Trace person from an old Facebook chat?

Tags: ip, facebook

I spoke with someone in January in the Facebook chat. The very next day he deleted his account.
The only thing I have is my copy of the conversation stored in my account.
Is there a way to trace his IP or find any information of him using that?

Comment: Facebook might have logs, but that's probably it.

Comment: What information could I get from those logs?

Comment: None. Facebook would be the only ones with access. They could access whatever they logged. They would be the only ones who know what they logged.

Comment: Just to be more clear, if the other person was blackmailing you, threatening you, etc. you could file a report to the police and they could, in turn, ask Facebook for the logs. Otherwise, there's nothing we can do.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook isn't a desktop application which stores log files on your computer like Skype would, but rather a web server application which has its own log files no one can have access to without getting in the web server.

The only two things you could possibly do are:

- (Legal) File a complaint to the police, if it's a legal matter, for them to ask Facebook for logs (but I won't bet on them giving these easily ;))
- (Illegal) Find a vulnerability on the web server that stores the logs, but you might as well give up on that (because you'll get in trouble and I doubt you will find any vulnerability anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can't figure out his IP because you don't "interact" with your chatpartner directly (P2P). You send a message to facebook and there webserver sents it to your partner. So only facebook (and presumably the nsa) knows the IP of your opposite. It's very unlikly that they hand it out to you. Maybe by court order, so good luck.